# how to add a button into QLPreviewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is it possible to add a new button into the toolBar or into the actionButton on the right top of QLpreviewController?

If yes, how i write the code?

Answer (score 1):

Although `QLPreviewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` changing navigation items has no effect. For example, this code should theoretically work but doesn't:

```
QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
previewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
   [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction 
                             target:self action:@selector(share)]
```

You can, however, add a toolbar to a QLPreviewController. First set up your toolbar to show when the view is loaded:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
}
```

Next, set your toolbarItems from the `QLPreviewController` delegate:

```
- (id)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)previewController 
                 previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)idx {

UIBarButtonItem *testButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                 target:self
                                                 action:@selector(testButtonTapped:)];

NSArray *myToolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:testButtonItem, nil];
previewController.toolbarItems = myToolbarItems;
[testButtonItem release];
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me on iOS 6. When enabling the toolbar the preview controller will just display the next/previous toolbar to navigate between multiple preview documents. Setting the toolbar items has no effect...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `rightBarButtonItem` in `viewDidLoad` of your custom `QLPreviewController` class, like this:

```
import QuickLook
import UIKit

class FileViewController: QLPreviewController {
     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourButton
     }
}
```